# plotnine is broken with matplotlib==3.6

Tags: matplotlib, plotnine

I am getting the following error with plotnine==0.9 and matplotlib==3.6.

```
 File "D:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\plotnine\stats\stat_density_2d.py", line 3, in <module>
    import matplotlib._contour as _contour
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib._contour'
```

If I downgrade matplotlib==3.5, the problem goes away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's discussed [here](https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/issues/619) and it's already fixed [here](https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/commit/c48d5a26ab0d0a54ed47bbefc6a83b5fcb2af616) Note that it's already merged to *main*.

It was due to a internal matplotlib call that is no longer supported and has been replaced.

So I guess you could choose between:

- downgrade to mlp 3.5.3
- install plotnine@main

till the next plotnine release.

Comment: How would one install plotnine@main?

Comment: this is another question you could easily search the answer because you will need it. It depends on the env handler/installer you are using. F.e: `pip install https://github.com/user/repo.git@branch` or using poetry `Package B= { git = "git@git.saas.tech/project-a.git", branch = "main" }`

Answer (score 0):

Carlos's answer is correct. However if anybody else, like me, is uncertain of how to install plotnine@main, **you can implement the [fix](https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/commit/c48d5a26ab0d0a54ed47bbefc6a83b5fcb2af616) rather easily**:

- Find the `site_packages` folder you python script uses. It usually is a subdirectory of the python version you are using, which can located reliably by trying to reinstall matplotlib or any other package you know you have access to, and checking the logs in the console. ex using `python -m pip install matplotlib`.
- Go down into the `site_packages/plotnine/stats` directory and open up the `stats_density_2d.py` file in your editor of choice.
- Apply & save the modifications made in the fix. Alternatively, overwrite the file with the one from the github.

Answer (score 0):

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib._contour'

Issues with matplotlib 3.6.1  and
plotnine 0.9.0

K.I.S.S.
in terminal:

```
pip show matplotlib   #enables you to check version
pip install matplotlib==3.5   #revert and problem is resolved for now.
```

no more:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib._contour'
resolves issue for now that will stop progress...